# Writing a program that will filter the integer solutions

Tags: equation-solving, programming, code-request, system, code

I've the following equation:

```
b==(-12 + 
  Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
   3 (-4 + r)^2 + 12 a^2 (-2 + r) - 4 a (-5 + r) (-2 + r) + 
    4 a^3 (-2 + r)^2] + 3 r)/(6 (-2 + r))
```

And $r$ is a given number and I'll run $a$ from $2$ to a given number n, which are all integers.

How can I write a code that will give me only an output of $b$ when the equation gives an integer back?

---

For example, when I use $r=4$ and use the following code:

```
Table[Sqrt[a (1 + a) (1 + 2 a)]/Sqrt[6], {a, 1, 100, 1}]
```

It will find that $a=24$ gives $b=70$, so I want to see only that solution.

Maybe I can use the `If[]` function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve). Your equation:

```
eqn[r_] := b == (-12 + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[3 (-4 + r)^2 + 12 a^2 (-2 + r) - 4 a (-5 + r) (-2 + r) + 4 a^3 (-2 + r)^2] + 3 r)/(6 (-2 + r))
```

Using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) (with $r=4$):

```
Solve[eqn[4] && 1 < a < 100, {a, b}, Integers]
```

> {{a -> 24, b -> 70}}

Using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) (with $r=11$):

```
Solve[eqn[11] && 1 < a < 100, {a, b}, Integers]
```

> {{a -> 25, b -> 73}}

Answer (score 5):

You might try `IntegerQ`

```
Table[b = (-12 +Sqrt[3] Sqrt[3 (-4 + r)^2 + 12 a^2 (-2 + r) - 4 a (-5 + r) (-2+ r) +4 a^3 (-2 + r)^2] + 3 r)/(6 (-2 + r)) /. r -> 4;
If[IntegerQ[b], {b, a}, Nothing], {a, 2, 50}]
(*{{70, 24}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) here:

```
b[r_, a_] := (-12 + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[3 (-4 + r)^2 + 12 a^2 (-2 + r) - 4 a (-5 + r) (-2 + r) + 4 a^3 (-2 + r)^2] + 3 r)/(6 (-2 + r));
```

With `r=4`

```
Cases[Table[b[4, a], {a, 2, 100}], _Integer]
```

> {70}

If you want to retrieve `{a,b}` pairs:

```
Cases[Table[{a, b[4, a]}, {a, 2, 100}], {_, _Integer}]
```

> {{24, 70}}

It's interesting to look at `{a,b}` points for a bunch of `r` values:

```
t = Cases[
       Table[Cases[Table[{a, b[r, a]}, {a, 2, 100}], {_, _Integer}], {r, 3, 20}], Except[{}]];

ListPlot[t, AxesLabel -> {a, b}]
```

[image]